# How to find most important category features relative to target for Regression models?

Tags: regression, categories, correlation

For the numerical features in Regression models, one can use the correlation function to find out the most important numerical features. For example,

```
corr=train.corr()
corr.sort_values(['SalePrice'], ascending = False, inplace = True)
print(corr.SalePrice)
```

The above script can rank the feature correlation to SalePrice for numerical features.

How do you do similar task for category features?

Answer (score 1):

There is no correlation measure for categorical features, however you could run an ANOVA to find if there exist differences in the categories and then use t-tests or something similar to find which are significant and possibly rank them by p-values.

Comment: ranking by p value is generally a bad idea and not recommended because it is influenced by a lot of things besides the strength of the relationship (e.g. measurement error). In other words, a p value of .001 does not necessarily indicate a stronger relationship than .05